# Visual Studio 2012 Intellisense in CSS editor suggests strange things

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2012

I have RTM version of VS 2012, and it's great - but intellisense in VS11 in CSS editor doesn't suggest parameter info, but ... something else, I'm not quite sure what is that actually, it looks like some sample.

To be clear, this is what I get (start VS11 without solution, FILE -> New -> File, file type Styles Sheet):

[image: Intellisense in CSS editor in VS11]

And this is what I get in VS10 (and what I'd really like to have in VS11):

[image]

This is just a sample with "margin"; I tried resetting preferences, clean install of VS11, etc. It behaves the same way with or without solution.

I suspect the problem is between keyboard and chair, but I didn't find any clue in VS11 preferences, or googling any combination of "intellisense css visual studio 2012", etc.

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct suggestion!.. It is basically giving you an example of what you can put as a value.

It is very useful for other CSS3 properties where the value is more complex.

Comment: What the parameters actually *do* (the latter screenshot) is infinitely more useful than an example.

Comment: Well, if this is how CSS intellisense really suppose to work (I **hope** not!), it's a giant leap backwards. VS10's intellisense tells me the complete information about the subject; do you honestly believe that such functionality has even remotely any logic? What does that tell me about the property? The only information I can infer from such suggestion is that property margin can have 4 parameters, nothing else (and even such deduction is almost wrong). I'm sorry for such vocal comment, it's just pity that something what worked well is now useless.